# Como adicionar um laço de repetição (for) quando for preciso

Tags: javascript

Estou com um programa onde existem três parâmetros. Assim:

Esses três parâmetros são posições dentro do `m_aluno[w_i][w_j][w_k]);`, onde `w_i` pode receber uma posição informada pelo usuário ou não e isso serve para `w_j` e `w_k` também; Meu problema encontra-se onde, caso for informado um valor para `w_i` e logo `w_j` e `w_k` forem vazios, só deve ser iterado o `w_j` e o `w_k` que irão iniciar em `0` logo o `w_i` deve ficar na posição informada!

O meu caso é: "Quero adicionar um **laço de repetição** somente quando for preciso. Como fazer?"

Joguei no JSFiddle com todas `as condições` para melhor visualização (era para funcionar, mas não sei editar para que execute a função primeiro).

[Código que desejo diminuir ²](http://jsfiddle.net/gdd8cz07/5/)

Assim, existem `três for's`:

```
for (w_i=0; w_i<w_ii; w_i++) //primeiro
     {
     for (w_j=0; w_j<w_jj; w_j++) //segundo 
         {
         for (w_k=0; w_k<w_kk; w_k++) //terceiro
             {
```

- Caso o `w_i` não iniciar em `0` o **primeiro** `for` tem que sumir.
- Caso    o `w_j` não iniciar em `0` o **segundo** `for` tem que sumir.
- Caso o    `w_k` não iniciar em `0` o **terceiro** `for` tem que sumir.

O `w_i, w_j e w_k` só não irão iniciar em **0** caso o usuário informe algum valor para eles.

Comment: Qual linguagem voce esta usando?

Comment: Estou fazendo em `JavaScript`! Na verdade precisa ser em `JS` :x

Comment: Não entendo direito o que você está tentando fazer. O que significa "adicionar no for o valor"? Talvez ficasse mais claro se você desse um exemplo simplificado incluindo a sua entrada e a saida desejada

Comment: @hugomg irei editar para melhor entendimento!

Comment: @Alexandre `JS` = `JavaScript`

Comment: Sim eu sei @Thomas! No comentário acima estou afirmando que deve ser em `JS` ^^

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, o laço vai ser feito quando `w_i` for informado, iterando `w_k` e `w_j`. Mas até que valor você quer iterar as variáveis? O problema não ficou muito claro e a nomenclatura das variáveis deixa-o mais confuso ainda.

Comment: @Thomas coloquei no JSFiddle para mostrar como eu havia feito antes, não está rodando pois suponho que não esteja pegando a função! (não sei editar lá)

Comment: Fiquei com dúvida nessa parte: _caso for informado um valor para w_i e logo w_j e w_k forem vazios, só deve ser iterado o w_j e o w_k que irão iniciar em 0 logo o w_i deve ficar na posição informada!_.

Basicamente, caso seja informado o Colégio, só a Sala e Matéria deve ser iterada no `for`?

Comment: Sim, e seria a mesma coisa se fosse: Foi informado só a sala, então somente o colégio e a matéria deverão iterar no `for`. No exemplo do JSFiddle tem os casos que podem ocorrer!

Comment: Esses 3 laços, então, não vão ficar aninhados, conforme o código dá a aparecer, certo? Eles vão iterar independentemente, conforme aqueles que NÃO forem informados... é isso?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo @Thomas

Comment: @Alexandre percebo que precisa de ajuda, esse código não é possivel de manter dessa maneira... Pode explicar também o que quer fazer? Qual é a funcionalidade que precisa, para podermos ajudar a refazer esse código que está demasiado complexo.

Comment: Claro @Sergio, minha finalidade é: Eu estou inserindo dentro do `m_aluno[w_i][w_j][w_k]` valores em determinadas posições ( 0 , 0 , 0 ). E depois de inserir eu gostaria de pesquisar o que contém nessas determinadas posições! Por isso é o meu caso de jogar o valor informado (que seria a posição) dentro do `w_i` ou `w_j` ou `w_k` ou até mesmo três ou dois valores!

Comment: @Alexandre Mas uma `Sala`, para existir, tem que estar ligada à um `Colégio`, certo? Por exemplo, para listar as `Salas` disponíveis, não seria mais fácil obrigar o usuário a escolher um `Colégio` antes ao invés de listar todas as `Salas` de todos os `Colégios`?

Comment: Nesse caso, para escolher um `w_j`, precisa escolher um `w_i`. Aliás, por que não chamar de `indice_colegio`? O propósito da variável ficaria mais claro no código.

Comment: Sim está correto o que você afirmou, mas se caso for informado `2 colégios` `2 salas` e `2 matérias`. Você concorda que no `colégio 1` teria `2 salas` e `2 matérias` e no `colégio 2` a mesma coisa certo?

Comment: Assim se caso ele quiser listar os valores que estiverem somente na `sala 2`, ele irá mostrar do `colégio 1` e do `colégio 2`!